# Forward declare entities in C standard library?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, forward-declaration

Is it legal to forward declare structs and functions provided by the C standard library?

My background is C++ in which the answer is no. The primary reason for this is that a struct or class mandated by the C++ standard library can be a template behind the scenes and may have "secret" template parameters and so cannot be properly declared with a naive non-template declaration. Even if a user does figure out exactly how to forward declare a particular entity in a particular version of a particular implementation, the implementation is not obliged to *not break* that declaration in future versions.

I don't have a copy of any C standard at hand but obviously there are no templates in C.

So is it legal to forward declare entities in the C standard library?

Another reason that entities in the C++ standard library may not be forward declared is that headers provided by the implementation need not follow the normal rules. For example, in a recent question I asked if a C++ header provided by the implementation need be an actual file and the answer was no. I don't know if any of that applies to C.

The C standard library is used by both C and C++ but for this question I'm only asking about C.

Comment: Yes you can forward declare functions and structs in C. You can make your compiler know that there is a definition somewhere and just have declarations in a header file

Comment: AFAIK, you surely can forward declare the `C` standard library functions thereby removing the requirement of including the corresponding header file, but think that's not _recommended._

Comment: @SouravGhosh Things that are not recommended but usually work are those funny edge cases of language lawyering I'm asking about!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forward declarations of structs are always permissible in C.  However, not very many types can be used this way.  For example, you can't use a forward declaration for `FILE` simply because the tag name of the struct is not specified (and theoretically, it may not be a struct at all).

Section 7.1.4 paragraph 2 of n1570 gives you permission to do the same with functions:

> Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a
>   header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its
>   associated header.

This used to be rather common.  I think the reasoning here is that hard drives are slow, and fewer `#include` means faster compile times.  But this isn't the 1980s any more, and we all have fast CPUs and fast hard drives, so a few `#include` aren't even noticed.

```
void *malloc(size_t);
void abort(void);

/* my code here */
```

Comment: What about forward declarations of structs?

Comment: @Praxeolitic: "Forward declarations of structs are always permissible."

Comment: @Praxeolitic: OTOH, I don't know of any structure which is declared in a standard header where the implementation details are specified. So the question may not arise at all. If you figure out how a structure is declared in a certain implementation, you can forward-declare it.

Comment: @mafso: Forward declaration of a struct means just specifying the name of the struct but not completing the type, e.g., `struct timespec;`, there's nothing else in a forward declaration so you can't screw it up.

Comment: `malloc` cannot be declared without reference to a type in a header: you need to include at least `<stddef.h>` in order for `size_t` to be declared. By a strict reading, then, `malloc` may not be declared by the user at all.

Comment: @hvd: I think that depends on what "a header" means: whether you interpret "a header" to refer to "any header in the standard library whatsoever", or "a header which you haven't included"... I'm not sure that the "strict reading" is entirely reasonable.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Then why the difference in wording: "a header" versus "its associated header"? I actually do believe my interpretation is not only reasonable, but quite possibly the intended one. The permission is mainly to cater to old code that did not bother with any of the standard library headers at all. But I was wrong even then: there is a valid declaration of `malloc` without reference to any type defined in any header: `void *malloc();`. And as long as one such declaration exists, the function may be declared by the user, not necessarily using that specific form.

Comment: Ick. Whether `void *malloc();` is valid depends on the implementation. An implementation could conceivably make `size_t` a typedef for `unsigned short`, and a quick search shows that this is actually done on some real implementations in the embedded world.

Comment: @hvd: I'm assuming here that you have done `#include <stddef.h>` but not `#include <stdlib.h>`, so you have the `size_t` typedef.  Defining your own `size_t` typedef sounds risky.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, I understand that. The mistake I made is in my previous two comments is that I thought `void *malloc(); void free(); int main() { free(malloc(sizeof(int))); }` would be valid, and that therefore `#include <stddef.h>` / `void *malloc(size_t s);` would be valid too since `malloc` *could* be declared without relying on any standard headers. But actually, the former is invalid, so that says nothing about whether the latter is valid.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can this is perfectly valid.
this can be done with the standard library too.

```
double atof(const char *);

int main() {
    double t = atof("13.37");
    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>
```

Similiar things can be done with structs, variables etc.

I would recommend you read the wiki page which features some c examples:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration

this is specified in the c standard, Section 7.1.4 paragraph 2 of n1570

Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its associated header.

Comment: well, the question is about standard library functions.

Comment: The `fopen()` declaration isn't useful because you need a declaration for `FILE`, which is in `<stdio.h>`, which means you already have a declaration for `fopen()`.

Comment: true made the declaration with `atof()` instead