# Legal to forward declare C standard library entities but not C++ standard library entities?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

Can entities in the C standard library legally be forward declared in C++?

I just asked this same question but for C and so far the answer seems to be yes.

[Forward declare entities in C standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27720258/1128289)

I know that entities in the C++ standard library cannot be forward declared for the reasons given in the linked question above. Before thinking of this question I would have said that the C standard library is part of the C++ standard library and therefore entities in the C standard library cannot be forward declared in C++.

Now I'm not sure. It would be surprising if the C++ standard mandates something about the C standard library that the C standard does not.

My understanding is that in practice, implementations of C++ tend to come with an implementation of C and the same header files and libraries are used for each (but optionally rebranded as  for C++). So in practice, forward declarations of entities in the C standard library will likely compile just fine in C++. Still, I'm curious about what the C++ standard mandates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that C++ and C are not compatible at the object level... For example it's different to write:

```
double atof(const char *);
```

and

```
extern "C" {
    double atof(const char *);
}
```

Comment: Name mangling is a very good point I hadn't thought of. Still, it would be odd if the first forward declaration you show would not be legal.

Comment: As far as I can recall only a pretty obscure compiler, CC on Solaris?, diagnosed mismatch between C and C++. But that was purely a formal thing, it could be turned off. The practical problem is when you need a static class member function as a C callback, and for the purely formal have to introduce an extra `extern "C"` function that calls the function you'd like to use. At one time I didn't know that and just happily used ordinary static member function. Now that I know, I think the language needs fixing in that regard...

Comment: `double atof(const char*); #include <stdlib.h>` doesn't compile on most platforms. On linux, even `extern "C" double atof(const char*); #include <stdlib.h>` doesn't compile because of `throw()`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, Sun C++ does indeed diagnose that, on both Solaris and Linux. But in Sun (now Oracle)'s documentation, it is mentioned that with some other compilers, a function with C linkage is not ABI-compatible with a function with C++ linkage. On those other compilers, "fixing" the language to require the types to be treated the same is pretty much impossible. I know the EDG front-end can also track language linkage, but whether compilers using the EDG front-end make use of that is left to those compilers.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf At any rate, the problem here isn't so much the language linkage of the function type, the language linkage of the name is a much bigger problem, on pretty much every implementation there is.